# React history.push location.state is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass props via history.push, but location.state is undefined in the next component. Interestingly, I can pass a value using hash and search, just not state. The initial component is a functional one that imports useHistory via react-router-dom and initializes it using useHistory(), and the next component is a class and am importing withRouter and have wrapped the export.

I am using React Router v5.2.0, and my code looks like:

```
const location = {
            pathname: `/dashboard`,
            state: { detail: 'test' }
        }

        history.push(location);
```

And in the next component, I am trying to access the detail props as follows:

```
let detail = this.props.location.state;
```

this.props.history.location.state is also undefined.

I would appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Comment: can you upload your code in codesandbox? after calling the `history.push`, your state is also undefined?

Comment: the location.state is undefined. i've tried passing along just a string as well instead of an object but no change.

Comment: @dev_dy any success? I am facing a similar issue